# Is there a way for tkcalendar to display more than one Date Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am working on a database entry application and am using tkinter and tkcalendar for the GUI using Python 3.8.  I've made a scratch piece of code below illustrating the error I'm seeing when trying to initialize two DateEntry widgets in the same window.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkcalendar as tkdate

class root(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.DE1 = tkdate.DateEntry(self)
        self.DE1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.DE2 = tkdate.DateEntry(self)
        self.DE2.grid(row=2, column=0)


app = root()
app.mainloop()
```

The traceback doesn't seem to give much information but I'll paste it here regardless; please note that the multiple instances of the DateEntry widget being created seem to be causing the exit code 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pmo/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 19, in <module>
    app = root()
  File "C:/Users/pmo/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.DE2 = tkdate.DateEntry(self)
  File "C:\Users\pmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 105, in __init__
    self._setup_style()
  File "C:\Users\pmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 160, in _setup_style
    self.style.map('DateEntry', **maps)
  File "C:\Users\pmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 403, in map
    self.tk.call(self._name, "map", style, *_format_mapdict(kw)),
_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name r

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Curiously, I'm able to place two calendar widgets with no problem but when trying to utilize two or more DateEntry widgets the entire application fails.  I've checked online but don't see anyone else who has had this particular problem using tkcalendar.  Does anyone have an idea how to interpret this error or better yet, know how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Known problem with tkcalendar and Python 3.8.  See https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/61 for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on jasonharper's answer and link: https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/61

The fix posted by the creator here does seem to resolve the issue when the library is updated using this (I am on Windows 10, x64 if it is useful to anyone): https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/tree/fix_63

Hopefully it will be pushed into the master library!